# C - share double using pthread cause segfault

Tags: c, pthreads

I wrote a program to demonstrate this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include <time.h>       /* clock_t, clock, CLOCKS_PER_SEC */
#include <math.h>       /* sqrt */
struct thread_args
{

    double* producer_clock;
    double* producer_time;
    double* consumer_time;
    double* consumer_clock;



};
void *producer(void* thread_args){
  struct thread_args* thread_arg=(struct thread_args*)thread_args;
    double* producer_time=(double*)(thread_arg->producer_time);
    double* producer_clock=(double*)(thread_arg->producer_clock);
    double* consumer_time=(double*)(thread_arg->consumer_time);
    double* consumer_clock=(double*)(thread_arg->consumer_clock);
    *producer_time=0;
    *producer_clock=0;
    *consumer_time=0;
    *consumer_clock=0;
}
int main(){
  pthread_t tid1;
  double* producer_time=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
       double* producer_clock=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
       double* consumer_time=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
    double* consumer_clock=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
    struct thread_args* thread_arg;
    thread_arg=(struct thread_args*)malloc(sizeof(struct thread_args*));
    thread_arg->producer_time=producer_time;
    thread_arg->producer_clock=producer_clock;
    thread_arg->consumer_time=consumer_time;
    thread_arg->consumer_clock=consumer_clock;
    pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,producer,(void*)thread_arg);
    pthread_join(tid1,NULL);
}
```

It will cause segfault. But if I replace double* with int*. It will run without error. My environment is Ubuntu 18.04 compiling using gcc. I don't know if my code is wrong..

Comment: With rare exception, if your program segfaults then yes, its code is wrong.

Comment: I think what is important is where is wrong.. It works with 3 double pointer in thread_args but not four. That blows my mind.

Comment: Advice: just because you want a pointer does not mean you need dynamic allocation.  Often -- but not always -- it is easier and better to get one by just applying the address-of operator (`&`) to a statically or dynamically-allocated variable.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I do that just because & does not work

Comment: Your program is wrong at least in that the `producer()` function declares that it returns `void *` (which is needful for it to be used as a thread start function), but *it does not actually return a value*.  The result of calling it is therefore undefined.  Your compiler really ought to be warning you about that.  In fact, I know that GCC emits such warnings.

Comment: Additionally, you need to check the return value of every `malloc()` call.  `malloc()` can fail, in which case it will return a null pointer, and subsequently trying to dereference such a pointer will produce undefined behavior.  Such a failure would be surprising in a program the size of yours, but I urge you to cultivate good coding habits.

Comment: No. I checked and allocation does not fail. I think it is a rare circumstance in a multi-process system but I really need 4 shared double to record the time. But I will improve my coding habits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two *bona fide* errors in your program.  The first, I already covered in comments: your `producer()` function is declared to return a value, but it does not actually do so.  As a result, calling this function produces undefined behavior.  Since you don't actually use the return value, you can fix this simply by making the function return `NULL`.

But it is probably more impactful that your `main()` function allocates too little space for `thread_arg`:

> ```
>     thread_arg=(struct thread_args*)malloc(sizeof(struct thread_args*));
> ```

You are allocating space the size of a pointer, but you need space enough for a `struct thread_args`, which is certainly larger (on Ubuntu) because it contains four pointers.  C does not require pointers to different object types to be the same size, but on Linux, they are.  Thus, a correct allocation would be

```
    thread_arg = (struct thread_args*) malloc(sizeof(struct thread_args));
```

HOWEVER, in C, it is poor form to cast the result of `malloc()`, the language does not require it, and doing so can mask errors that your compiler otherwise would report to you.  (This is different in C++.)  Thus, this would be better form:

```
    thread_arg = malloc(sizeof(struct thread_args));
```

The same applies to all assignments where one side is a pointer to void and the other is a pointer to any object type, and also to passing arguments to non-varargs functions.

But we can do yet better.  Note that it's not immediately clear from that statement itself what the type of `thread_arg` is, so as to verify that the right number of bytes is allocated.  Consider also what might happen if `thread_arg` were later changed to have a different type, and fixing that allocation to correspond were overlooked.  These problems can be solved by setting the size via an expression of the needed type, instead of via that type's name:

```
    thread_arg = malloc(sizeof(*thread_arg));
```

Note well that the argument of `sizeof()` is not evaluated (unless its type is variable-length, which is not the case here), so it is not a problem to use the expression `*thread_arg` before a value is assigned to `thread_arg`.  And the resulting statement is clearly and unequivocally correct.  In English, it says: "allocate space the size of a thing that `thread_arg` points to, and assign a pointer to that space to `thread_arg`".

Comment: Thanks for the clear and detailed explanation! That saves my day. I really want up vote you but I just register the account.